# No keyboard after rebooting 14.04 for updates

Tags: 14.04, usb, updates, keyboard, lts

After rebooting my server to complete a few automatically installed updates, my USB keyboard no longer works and it won't boot past the grub screen. The keyboard still works in another PC.

I'm really hoping someone has a trick up their sleeve... Some background:

- The PC (i7 with either 8 or 16 GB RAM, can't recall) is only about 6 months old, running 14.04 LTS Server.
- Roughly 3 months ago I added kernel 3.15 (via a repository) and had been using that with no problems, across several successful reboots.
- I can't even get into the BIOS, as if the usb keyboard is dead (but again, it works in another PC).
- Hardware was fine up until that reboot so I'm reluctant to blame the motherboard or whatever other hardware, especially considering it does boot as far as grub with no errors or beeps.

I tried putting in a CD to boot off of but without the keyboard working to select Boot Menu or do anything in grub I feel really useless... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you can't get into the BIOS, this indicates that the problem is outside of anything OS-related. Try plugging the keyboard into a different USB port?

Comment: What happens if you use another computer's keyboard in the machine?  Also, just to be sure... you turned the computer completely off right, not just rebooted?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> right after turning on your computer (when BIOS messages appear). Then you may get a GRUB menu where you can select the older kernel to bool.

If that boots successfully, you have a workaround. (And that would mean the problem is caused by a kernel update, which is what happened to me.)